# cloning of the second scren instead of having a third screen on HDMI output

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi

I'm trying to setup a third screen.

It is recognized by the hardware, see the results below when I'm doing this `find /sys/devices/ -iname edid`

```
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-HDMI-A-1/edid
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-eDP-1/edid
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-HDMI-A-2/edid
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/drm/card0/card0-DP-1/edid
```

Yet when I'm doing a `xrandr`, HDMI-1 is connected but not HDMI-2

```
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

The strangest part is HDMI-1 is being cloned on HDMI-2 instead of being seen by the OS.

I've tried these 2 commands but nothing so far

```
sudo xrandr --addmode HDMI-2 1920x1080
sudo xrandr --output HDMI-2 --mode 1920x1080 --pos 0x0
```

If you want additional details, please leave a comment.

Thank you.

Comment: On what computer, using what graphics? Are you using X.org or Wayland? Do other screens display the same behaviour? Are there other possible connections? If so, have you tried them? Have you tried a different cable, in case it is not being detected correctly? You have not specified what desktop you are using. Try a different one, ideally, a less-demanding one. (E.g. on my work laptop, a Dell Latitude, KDE 5 can only drive 2 monitors correctly, and windows on the 3rd lose the window decorations. However, XFCE  seems to use less VRAM and is unaffected by this.)

Comment: Try booting your machine from as USB key with a less-demanding desktop -- e.g. if you're using GNOME 3, a heavyweight desktop that needs OpenGL compositing, try with Xubuntu. If you're using 20.04, try 20.10.

Comment: As I was talking to one of my mate, he asked me if the issue was not related to my splitter. I bought a splitter and thinking about it, the issue may lie here.